# Split array of structs from JSON into Dataframe rows in SPARK

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I am reading Kafka through Spark Structured streaming. The input Kafka message is of the below JSON format:

```js
[
  {
    "customer": "Jim",
    "sex": "male",
    "country": "US"  
  },
  {
    "customer": "Pam",
    "sex": "female",
    "country": "US"
  } 
]
```

I have the define the schema like below to parse it:

```scala
val schemaAsJson = ArrayType(StructType(Seq(
      StructField("customer",StringType,true),
      StructField("sex",StringType,true),
      StructField("country",StringType,true))),true)
```

My code looks like this,

```scala
df.select(from_json($"col", schemaAsJson) as "json")
  .select("json.customer","json.sex","json.country")
```

The current output looks like this,

```
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
|      customer|             sex|country         |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
|    [Jim, Pam]|  [male, female]|        [US, US]|
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
```

**Expected output:**

```
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
|      customer|             sex|         country|
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
|           Jim|            male|              US|
|           Pam|          female|              US|
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
```

How do I split array of structs into individual rows as above? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need explode column before selecting.

```
df.select(explode_outer(from_json($"value", schemaAsJson)) as "json")
.select("json.customer","json.sex","json.country").show()
```

Comment: I tried it. I am getting this error: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`json.customer`' given input columns: [col];

Comment: Updated the answer, check now

Comment: Sorry, that's  typo

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as expected! My Actual data is little bit more complex in nested structure. Like within the parent struct I will have another array of struct like "previous employment": [ {"emp1Details":""}, {"emp2Details":""} ]. I am yet to try you solution on that. But will the explode_outer still work for them?

Comment: For all array columns, you can use explode function.